# Ember.Object computed property returning an object

Tags: ember.js

So I have an Ember Object:

```
App.User = Ember.Object.extend({
    firstName: null, 
    lastName: null, 
    dob: Ember.Object.create({
        day: null,
        month: null,
        year: null,
        display: function () {
            var self = this,
            day = (self.get('day') < 10 ? "0" : "") + self.get('day'),
            month = (self.get('month') < 10 ? "0" : "") + self.get('month'),
            year = self.get('year');

            return day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
        }.property('day', 'month', 'year')
    })
});
```

And on my Controller - I am creating a version of the object - which is then bound to by a form:

```
App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    user: App.User.create()
});
```

However - for some reason, whenever I try and get the dob.display computer property within my controller or in my view, I just get an object returned.

```
this.get('user.dob.display')

{{user.dob.display}}
```

Any ideas how to make sure it returns a string? This was working up until a couple of days ago when I updated from 1.0.0-pre2 to 1.0.0-pre4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `create`, but `createWithMixins`. This is the only way to define computed properties on object creation:

```
dob: Ember.Object.createWithMixins({
    day: null,
    month: null,
    year: null,
    display: function () {
        day = (this.get('day') < 10 ? "0" : "") + this.get('day'),
        month = (this.get('month') < 10 ? "0" : "") + this.get('month'),
        year = this.get('year');

        return day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
    }.property('day', 'month', 'year')
})
```

One remark: when setting properties in `extend` methods, each instance share the same object.
If you do not know that, [go read "Understanding Ember.Object" article written by Dan Gebhardt](http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object/) (this article could be a little bit outdated, but the idea is still the same).

Consequently, here, you have:

```
var user1 = App.User.create().get("dob").set("year", 1988);
var user2 = App.User.create();
console.log(user2.get("dob.year")); // => 1988
```

If you want to define objects that are different between instances, you have to override the `init` method like this:

```
App.User = Ember.Object.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super(); // do not forget that
        this.set('dob', Ember.Object.createWithMixins({
            // [code ommitted]
        }));
    }
});
```

But I suggest you to create a model `dob` instead of just create it each time you create a user.

You can try [this in a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lcoq/6Qv3L/1/).

Answer (score 0):

In pre4 you cannot define a computed property on a Ember.Object that is created.

**Not allowed**

```
dob: Ember.Object.create({
    day: null,
    month: null,
    year: null,
    display: function () {
        var self = this,
        day = (self.get('day') < 10 ? "0" : "") + self.get('day'),
        month = (self.get('month') < 10 ? "0" : "") + self.get('month'),
        year = self.get('year');

        return day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
    }.property('day', 'month', 'year')
})
```

It's only allowed to do this on Objects that is extended.

I have created a fiddle (abit modified) that works with your dob logic.

http://jsfiddle.net/Energiz0r/AeDAw/4/

Comment: Thanks, but my d/m/y properties are bound to some form fields on the view, so will this work if those values change post-setUpControllers?

Comment: @TommyKey this is not right, you just have to use `createWithMixins` instead of `create`, take a look at my answer

Comment: Yea that's true, but I didn't want to mention it because I feel that you shouldn't create(withMixins) an object inside another object that is extended.